# Using csv module to read ascii delimited text?

Tags: python, csv, newline

You may or may not be [aware](https://ronaldduncan.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/text-file-formats-ascii-delimited-text-not-csv-or-tab-delimited-text/) of [ASCII delimited text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text), which has the nice advantage of using non-keyboard characters for separating fields and lines.

Writing this out is pretty easy:

```
import csv

with open('ascii_delim.adt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=chr(31), lineterminator=chr(30))
    writer.writerow(('Sir Lancelot of Camelot', 'To seek the Holy Grail', 'blue'))
    writer.writerow(('Sir Galahad of Camelot', 'I seek the Grail', 'blue... no yellow!'))
```

And, sure enough, you get things dumped out properly. However, on reading, `lineterminator` does nothing, and if I try to do:

```
open('ascii_delim.adt', newline=chr(30))
```

It throws a `ValueError: illegal newline value:`

So how can I read in my ASCII delimited file? Am I relegated to doing `line.split(chr(30))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by effectively translating the end-of-line characters in the file into the newline characters `csv.reader` is hardcoded to recognize:

```
import csv

with open('ascii_delim.adt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=chr(31), lineterminator=chr(30))
    writer.writerow(('Sir Lancelot of Camelot', 'To seek the Holy Grail', 'blue'))
    writer.writerow(('Sir Galahad of Camelot', 'I seek the Grail', 'blue... no yellow!'))

def readlines(f, newline='\n'):
    while True:
        line = []
        while True:
            ch = f.read(1)
            if ch == '':  # end of file?
                return
            elif ch == newline:  # end of line?
                line.append('\n')
                break
            line.append(ch)
        yield ''.join(line)

with open('ascii_delim.adt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(readlines(f, newline=chr(30)), delimiter=chr(31))
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Output:

```
['Sir Lancelot of Camelot', 'To seek the Holy Grail', 'blue']
['Sir Galahad of Camelot', 'I seek the Grail', 'blue... no yellow!']
```

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) says:

> The reader is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and ignores lineterminator. This behavior may change in the future.

So the `csv` module cannot read CSV files that use custom line terminators.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was struggling with a similar problem all day. I wrote a function heavily inspired by @martineau that should solve it for you. My function is slower but can parse files delimited by any kind of string. Hope it helps!

```
import csv

def custom_CSV_reader(csv_file,row_delimiter,col_delimiter):

    with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:

        row = [];
        result = [];
        temp_row = ''
        temp_col = ''
        line = ''
        go = 1;

        while go == 1:
            while go == 1:
                ch = f.read(1)

                if ch == '':  # end of file?
                    go = 0

                if ch != '\n' and ch != '\t' and ch != ',':
                    temp_row = temp_row + ch
                    temp_col = temp_col + ch
                    line = line + ch

                if row_delimiter in temp_row:
                    line = line[:-len(row_delimiter)]

                    row.append(line)

                    temp_row = ''
                    line= ''

                    break

                elif col_delimiter in temp_col:
                    line = line[:-len(col_delimiter)]
                    row.append(line)
                    result.append(row)

                    row = [];
                    temp_col = ''
                    line = ''
                    break
    return result
```

Answer (score -1):

Per [the docs for `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> *newline* controls how universal newlines mode works (it only applies to text mode). It can be `None`, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and `'\r\n'`.

so `open` won't handle your file. Per [the `csv` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator):

> **Note** The `reader` is hard-coded to recognise either `'\r'` or `'\n'` as end-of-line, and ignores *lineterminator*.

so that won't do it either. I also looked into whether [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) was configurable, but it uses a defined set of boundaries.

> Am I relegated to doing `line.split(chr(30))`?

Looks that way, sorry!

Comment: Boo. That's what I expected based on what I looked at/tried.